# Web Services Automation Testing using Selenium

Tags: selenium

i would like to perform webservices testing( WSDL or REST Services) using selenium , ca anyone help me with this?

Comment: Your answer is way to broad. Use Google and help yourself. You have to write your own webservice-calls with Java or similiar because selenium doesn't integrate native WSDL or REST service support

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use Selenium to test these things.  Selenium is useful for automating the UI that interacts with said REST or WSDL services.  It (Selenium) should not be used for automating the services themselves.

Instead, use something like jMeter, SoapUI or even `curl`